# SharePoint 2013 workflow - how to set status when manually terminate workflow

Tags: workflow-activity, workflow-manager

I am developing a workflow using Vs 2013 for SharePoint 2013 on premise. 
I have used SetWorkflowStatus activity to set the status as workflow progress but if user manually terminate or cancel the workflow then how can I set the status to terminate or cancel? Or is there any way to catch the manually terminated or cancelled workflow ?